# Best way to generate PDF from a template using nodejs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Now, I'm looking for the solution to generate pdf (invoice with barcode, etc..) from template(html, css) in nodejs environment. I found there are several ways to do that such as [wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf), [phantom.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) & handlebars.js, [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf). What I'm concern is which is the best way to solve this problem.

Also, I have look at [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf), an client side generation, but it seem not suitable for production right now.

So, Anyone have used one of these library in production, please give me an advised.

Many thanks !

**UPDATED:**

Headless chromium is now ready for use.

Have some limitation (e.g: custom header, footer), but work great in almost cases.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

**UPDATED: 4/2019**

Now, Puppeteer is a major library for generating pdfs

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the invoice is on a static webpage, PhantomJS will allow you to generate a PDF . Here are a link to the [screen-capture section of the docs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html). It shows you how simple it is do perform this :)